# Disabling Older Versions of Secrets in Azure KeyVault

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-keyvault, azure-cli, terraform-provider-azure

Is there a way to Disable the Older Versions of Secrets , leaving only the latest version of secret enabled in a Azure keyVault.

I have huge number of secrets and every secret has multiple older version still enabled.

Can someone suggest a way or a #PowerShell / #AzureCLI / #Terraform way to do it in one go.

Answer (score 3):

On workarounds  you can disable the older version of secrets   through the azure portal only

**1)** Go to the portal select the your **key vault** and select the **secret**

[image]

[image]

**2)** After selecting secret -> **right click on secret** --> **disable**

[image]

Comment: This answer should have been accepted.

Comment: @WBuck it does not answer the question. OP was looking for a programmatic method.

Comment: @Tony no he wasn't, he was looking for "a way" to do it, including but not limited to programmatically doing it. Furthermore, since there is only a single way to accomplish the requested task; this is the answer (at least at the time of this writing).

Comment: @WBuck How does this resolve OP's issue in "one go"?

Comment: @Tony as noted, this is the *only* way to accomplish this task. It's this or nothing. That, in and on it's self **is** the answer. It cannot be done in "one go", it cannot be done programmatically. You either set in via the portal or you can't set it at all. That's the answer

Comment: @WBuck I posted a way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

This works in PowerShell 7 with module Az.KeyVault v4.10.2.

Firstly, it creates a list of secrets in the vault.  Secondly, it looks for prior versions for each secret.  It skips the most recent version and then disables any older ones.

```
$vault = 'vaultname'
$secrets = ( Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -vaultName $vault | Select-Object Name ).Name

ForEach ( $secret in $secrets ) {
   Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -vaultName $vault -name $secret -IncludeVersions | 
      Sort-Object Created -Descending | 
      Select-Object -Skip 1 | 
         ForEach-Object { 
            Set-AzKeyVaultSecretAttribute -vaultName $_.VaultName -name $_.Name -Version $_.Version -Enable $False 
         }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done selenium style using vanilla JavaScript. You can run this code in the browser console:

```
(
    () => {
            var intervalId = setInterval(()=>{
            var enableList = $('span:contains("Enabled")');
            console.log(enableList);
            if(enableList.length > 1){
                var secondEelement = enableList[1];
                console.log(secondEelement);
                secondEelement.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('contextmenu', { bubbles : true }));
                setTimeout(()=>{
                    $('li[role="menuitem"]').click();
                },1000);
            }
            else
            {
                clearInterval(intervalId);
            }
        },1500);
    }
)();
```

Time interval can be modified if you want it to run faster.

Give it a try if you want.